# Page won't disable scrolling

Tags: html, css

For whatever reason, my 1600x1200 image keeps its scrolling even though I've turned off overflow, which is something I thought would have done it. Here's my code...

```
body#login{
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url('images/login_images/background.jpg');
background-size: auto 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center; 
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
<body id="login">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-center logo-image">
        <h1><i class="fa fa-rebel fa-4x"></i></h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="">
    <!--<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><input type="email" />
    <div id="login-email"></div>-->
</div>
```

This creates a small horizontal and vertical scroll even though I had overflow set to hidden. I first noticed this when I saw my icon was off-center.

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Bootstrap columns need to be in rows to work properly.

Comment: Where did you set the overflow?

Comment: I had them, but took them out because it was creating an un-gradiented part on the horizontal scroll.

Comment: @j08691 sorry, I had taken it out because I was testing things. I've added it back to my post. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

the body has a margin or padding by your browser's default stylesheet.

Set the HTML and BODY elements to: padding:0;